Can't crosscompile tensorflow lite c library using camke
I need to use the tflite c library in a beaglebone black rev3 with this specs:
processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 2 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 995.32
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon vfpv3 tls vfpd32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x3
CPU part        : 0xc08
CPU revision    : 2

Hardware        : Generic AM33XX (Flattened Device Tree)
Revision        : 0000
Serial          : 2218SBB15982
ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.28-10) 2.28
gcc version 8.3.0

i'm trying to build the library using this toolchain : gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf
so like this tutto https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_cmake_arm I used this command first:
`
mkdir tflite_build
cd tflite_build
ARMCC_FLAGS="-march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon-vfpv3 -funsafe-math-optimizations -mfp16-format=ieee"
ARMCC_PREFIX=${HOME}/toolchains/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=${ARMCC_PREFIX}gcc \
  -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${ARMCC_PREFIX}g++ \
  -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="${ARMCC_FLAGS}" \
  -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="${ARMCC_FLAGS}" \
  -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON \
  -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Linux \
  -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=armv7 \
  ../tensorflow/lite/

but then I have errors when I run
cmake --build . -j

logs:
[ 15%] Building C object _deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/src/f32-rsum/gen/f32-rsum-neon-u12-acc3.c.o
cd /home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4/_deps/xnnpack-build && /home/ubuntu-16/toolchains/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -DEIGEN_MPL2_ONLY -DFXDIV_USE_INLINE_ASSEMBLY=0 -DNOMINMAX=1 -DPTHREADPOOL_NO_DEPRECATED_API=1 -DXNN_ENABLE_ARM_BF16=1 -DXNN_ENABLE_ARM_DOTPROD=1 -DXNN_ENABLE_ARM_FP16_SCALAR=1 -DXNN_ENABLE_ARM_FP16_VECTOR=1 -DXNN_ENABLE_ARM_I8MM=1 -DXNN_ENABLE_ASSEMBLY=1 -DXNN_ENABLE_AVX512AMX=0 -DXNN_ENABLE_AVX512FP16X=0 -DXNN_ENABLE_AVXVNNI=0 -DXNN_ENABLE_CPUINFO=1 -DXNN_ENABLE_DWCONV_MULTIPASS=0 -DXNN_ENABLE_GEMM_M_SPECIALIZATION=1 -DXNN_ENABLE_JIT=0 -DXNN_ENABLE_MEMOPT=1 -DXNN_ENABLE_RISCV_VECTOR=1 -DXNN_ENABLE_SPARSE=1 -DXNN_ENABLE_VSX=1 -I/home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/third_party/xla/third_party/tsl -I/home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/third_party/xla -I/home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4/xnnpack/src -I/home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4/pthreadpool-source/include -I/home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4/FXdiv-source/include -I/home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4/FP16-source/include -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon-vfpv3 -funsafe-math-optimizations -mfp16-format=ieee -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC -Wno-psabi -O2 -pthread -std=c99  -fno-math-errno  -marm  -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon  -MD -MT _deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/src/f32-rsum/gen/f32-rsum-neon-u12-acc3.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/src/f32-rsum/gen/f32-rsum-neon-u12-acc3.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/src/f32-rsum/gen/f32-rsum-neon-u12-acc3.c.o -c /home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4/xnnpack/src/f32-rsum/gen/f32-rsum-neon-u12-acc3.c
_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/build.make:17396: recipe for target '_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/src/qs8-vcvt/gen/qs8-vcvt-armsimd32-u4.c.o' failed
_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/build.make:17298: recipe for target '_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/src/qs8-qc8w-gemm/gen/qs8-qc8w-gemm-1x2c4-minmax-fp32-armsimd32.c.o' failed
_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/build.make:17564: recipe for target '_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/src/qu8-vcvt/gen/qu8-vcvt-armsimd32-u4.c.o' failed
_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/build.make:17410: recipe for target '_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/src/qs8-vcvt/gen/qs8-vcvt-armsimd32-u8.c.o' failed
_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/build.make:17592: recipe for target '_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/src/qu8-vlrelu/gen/qu8-vlrelu-armsimd32-u4.c.o' failed
_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/build.make:17424: recipe for target '_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/src/qs8-vlrelu/gen/qs8-vlrelu-armsimd32-u4.c.o' failed
_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/build.make:17326: recipe for target '_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/src/qs8-qc8w-gemm/gen/qs8-qc8w-gemm-2x2c4-minmax-fp32-armsimd32.c.o' failed
_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/build.make:17354: recipe for target '_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/src/qs8-qc8w-igemm/gen/qs8-qc8w-igemm-1x2c4-minmax-fp32-armsimd32.c.o' failed
_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/build.make:17578: recipe for target '_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/src/qu8-vcvt/gen/qu8-vcvt-armsimd32-u8.c.o' failed
_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/build.make:17480: recipe for target '_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/src/qu8-gemm/gen/qu8-gemm-2x1c4-minmax-fp32-armsimd32.c.o' failed
_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/build.make:17452: recipe for target '_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/src/qu8-gemm/gen/qu8-gemm-1x1c4-minmax-fp32-armsimd32.c.o' failed
_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/build.make:17508: recipe for target '_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/src/qu8-igemm/gen/qu8-igemm-1x1c4-minmax-fp32-armsimd32.c.o' failed
_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/build.make:17340: recipe for target '_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/src/qs8-qc8w-igemm/gen/qs8-qc8w-igemm-1x1c4-minmax-fp32-armsimd32.c.o' failed
_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/build.make:17312: recipe for target '_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/src/qs8-qc8w-gemm/gen/qs8-qc8w-gemm-2x1c4-minmax-fp32-armsimd32.c.o' failed
_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/build.make:17466: recipe for target '_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/src/qu8-gemm/gen/qu8-gemm-1x2c4-minmax-fp32-armsimd32.c.o' failed
_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/build.make:17368: recipe for target '_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/src/qs8-qc8w-igemm/gen/qs8-qc8w-igemm-2x1c4-minmax-fp32-armsimd32.c.o' failed
_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/build.make:17284: recipe for target '_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/src/qs8-qc8w-gemm/gen/qs8-qc8w-gemm-1x1c4-minmax-fp32-armsimd32.c.o' failed
_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/build.make:17494: recipe for target '_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/src/qu8-gemm/gen/qu8-gemm-2x2c4-minmax-fp32-armsimd32.c.o' failed
_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/build.make:17536: recipe for target '_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/src/qu8-igemm/gen/qu8-igemm-2x1c4-minmax-fp32-armsimd32.c.o' failed
_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/build.make:17382: recipe for target '_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/src/qs8-qc8w-igemm/gen/qs8-qc8w-igemm-2x2c4-minmax-fp32-armsimd32.c.o' failed
_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/build.make:17550: recipe for target '_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/src/qu8-igemm/gen/qu8-igemm-2x2c4-minmax-fp32-armsimd32.c.o' failed
_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/build.make:17522: recipe for target '_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/src/qu8-igemm/gen/qu8-igemm-1x2c4-minmax-fp32-armsimd32.c.o' failed
[ 15%] Linking CXX static library libabsl_log_internal_globals.a
cd /home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/log && /usr/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/absl_log_internal_globals.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
cd /home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/log && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/absl_log_internal_globals.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
[ 15%] Linking CXX static library libabsl_examine_stack.a
cd /home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/debugging && /usr/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/absl_examine_stack.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
cd /home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/debugging && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/absl_examine_stack.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/home/ubuntu-16/toolchains/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar qc libabsl_log_internal_globals.a CMakeFiles/absl_log_internal_globals.dir/internal/globals.cc.o
/home/ubuntu-16/toolchains/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib libabsl_log_internal_globals.a
/home/ubuntu-16/toolchains/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar qc libabsl_examine_stack.a CMakeFiles/absl_examine_stack.dir/internal/examine_stack.cc.o
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4'
/home/ubuntu-16/toolchains/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib libabsl_examine_stack.a
[ 15%] Built target absl_log_internal_globals
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4'
[ 15%] Built target absl_examine_stack
[ 15%] Linking CXX static library libabsl_kernel_timeout_internal.a
cd /home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/synchronization && /usr/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/absl_kernel_timeout_internal.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
cd /home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/synchronization && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/absl_kernel_timeout_internal.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/home/ubuntu-16/toolchains/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar qc libabsl_kernel_timeout_internal.a CMakeFiles/absl_kernel_timeout_internal.dir/internal/kernel_timeout.cc.o
/home/ubuntu-16/toolchains/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib libabsl_kernel_timeout_internal.a
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:6932: recipe for target '_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/microkernels-all.dir/all' failed
[ 15%] Built target absl_kernel_timeout_internal
[ 15%] Linking CXX static library libabsl_log_entry.a
cd /home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/log && /usr/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/absl_log_entry.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
cd /home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/log && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/absl_log_entry.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/home/ubuntu-16/toolchains/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar qc libabsl_log_entry.a CMakeFiles/absl_log_entry.dir/log_entry.cc.o
[ 15%] Linking CXX static library libabsl_random_internal_distribution_test_util.a
/home/ubuntu-16/toolchains/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib libabsl_log_entry.a
cd /home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/random && /usr/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/absl_random_internal_distribution_test_util.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
cd /home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/random && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/absl_random_internal_distribution_test_util.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4'
/home/ubuntu-16/toolchains/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar qc libabsl_random_internal_distribution_test_util.a CMakeFiles/absl_random_internal_distribution_test_util.dir/internal/chi_square.cc.o CMakeFiles/absl_random_internal_distribution_test_util.dir/internal/distribution_test_util.cc.o
[ 15%] Built target absl_log_entry
/home/ubuntu-16/toolchains/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib libabsl_random_internal_distribution_test_util.a
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4'
[ 15%] Built target absl_random_internal_distribution_test_util
[ 15%] Linking CXX static library libabsl_random_internal_pool_urbg.a
cd /home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/random && /usr/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/absl_random_internal_pool_urbg.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
cd /home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/random && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/absl_random_internal_pool_urbg.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/home/ubuntu-16/toolchains/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar qc libabsl_random_internal_pool_urbg.a CMakeFiles/absl_random_internal_pool_urbg.dir/internal/pool_urbg.cc.o
/home/ubuntu-16/toolchains/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib libabsl_random_internal_pool_urbg.a
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4'
[ 15%] Built target absl_random_internal_pool_urbg
[ 15%] Linking CXX static library libabsl_crc32c.a
cd /home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/crc && /usr/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/absl_crc32c.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
cd /home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/crc && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/absl_crc32c.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/home/ubuntu-16/toolchains/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar qc libabsl_crc32c.a CMakeFiles/absl_crc32c.dir/crc32c.cc.o CMakeFiles/absl_crc32c.dir/internal/crc_memcpy_fallback.cc.o CMakeFiles/absl_crc32c.dir/internal/crc_memcpy_x86_64.cc.o CMakeFiles/absl_crc32c.dir/internal/crc_non_temporal_memcpy.cc.o
/home/ubuntu-16/toolchains/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib libabsl_crc32c.a
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4'
[ 15%] Built target absl_crc32c
[ 15%] Linking CXX static library libabsl_log_globals.a
cd /home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/log && /usr/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/absl_log_globals.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
cd /home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/log && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/absl_log_globals.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/home/ubuntu-16/toolchains/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar qc libabsl_log_globals.a CMakeFiles/absl_log_globals.dir/globals.cc.o
/home/ubuntu-16/toolchains/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib libabsl_log_globals.a
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4'
[ 15%] Built target absl_log_globals
[ 15%] Linking CXX static library libabsl_flags_marshalling.a
cd /home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/flags && /usr/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/absl_flags_marshalling.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
cd /home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/flags && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/absl_flags_marshalling.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/home/ubuntu-16/toolchains/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar qc libabsl_flags_marshalling.a CMakeFiles/absl_flags_marshalling.dir/marshalling.cc.o
/home/ubuntu-16/toolchains/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib libabsl_flags_marshalling.a
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4'
[ 15%] Built target absl_flags_marshalling
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu-16/Downloads/tensorflow-master/build4'
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed

when cross compile using bazel the .so dont work in the target cause the .so depend on GLIC higher then 2.28
I expect having a tflite .so library for armv7 arch32depending on maximum glibc 2.28

You always need to include errors in the question, people cannot guess what errors you get.
